# How to avoid ambiguity defining continuity / differentiability of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

A function $f(x):\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb R^1$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)$ exists (in a sense is bounded) in any direction to origin.

Is this function continuous in the origin, or in order to be continuous there it has to have the same limit value there in all directions?

How to differentiate such two cases defining function continuity?

Same question arises concerning differentiability.

I appreciate any explanations.

Comment: No, to be continuous at the origin it must have the same limit in all directions.  But even that is not enough.  It also must have that same limit when approached in ways other than along straight lines.  Some of the point of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity is to cover cases like this.

Comment: If "in all directions" means "along any curve" then it is true. If you restrict any curve to any ray then it is false.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be continuous, the limit must coincide in all directions and the function must assume that value at the origin.

However, even more is needed.
The limit must coincide regardless of the path taken towards the origin (directions correspond to straight lines).
It is poosible that the limit exist and coincide for all directions but fails to exist/coincide for some other path.
A classical example is

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2},$$

which approaches $0$ along any line but is constant and equal to $\frac12$ along the curve $y=x^2$.

For differentiability, we have the same situation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And what kind of "continuity" is the case when the limit is just limited (being say continues along any straight path to, of even through)?

Comment: Do you mean perhaps 'bounded near the origin'? Admittedly, this is weaker than saying that all directional limits exist, but I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: How to formally characterize a function which is $C^2$ continuous on $R^n \ 0$, is ($C^0$) continuous in origin and has bounded derivatives in any direction there (other than in same these words)?

Comment: Sorry for typo, I mean $R^n\setminus 0$ there in place of  $R^n   0$.

Comment: Just checking: you mean $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f$ has bounded directional derivatives near $0$?

Comment: Thank you very much @Fimpellizieri. This is exactly what I mean. Sounds like music to my ear. The only thing is that I expected that this part: "_$f$ has bounded directional derivatives near $0$_" could be expressed as some feature of the function at  $0$, like some type of continuity or differentiability at a point.

Comment: Humm. I don't think there is a 'canonical' term for these functions. I might be wrong, but I don't know of them. That's one of those situations where you get to name things! Call them 'bdd functions' or something that makes sense haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61956/discussion-between-mirodin-and-fimpellizieri).